# Is there any significance to the name Avenue 5?

Tags: avenue-5

Does the name of the eponymous "Avenue 5" have any significance, either in-universe, or perhaps as a writer's in-joke? It seems a rather unusual name for a ship, so it seems to me that there must be something in-universe to explain it, and if not, it must have some foundation in a production in-joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to **Armando Iannucci**, the creator of the show](https://twitter.com/Aiannucci/status/1240027866412331008):

> In case you haven’t worked it out yet, it’s ‘Avenue 5’ in memory of Fifth Avenue, where he said he could shoot someone in the face and still get elected.

Comment: "He", being Donald Trump.